# Obtain variable between tag and append to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that was developed by someone else. I want to take the variable that they are displaying on when the page loads from the following tag `<h3 id="TAGS"></h3>` and append that to a this example URL `http://someurl.com/<variable>.`

I'm not a JavaScript person so any help would be appreciated.

I tried the following which did not work

```
var myURL = $('#TAGS').innerHTML
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="window.location.href=\'http://someurl.com/' + myURL + '\'"/>
```

Comment: If you're trying to select an element with an ID, you need to use the # to denote that - `$('#TAGS').innerHTML;`

Comment: Use $('#TAGS').html();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JAVASCRIPT + jQuery:**
Create a global variable like `var downloadURL = ""` and make a function in jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var myURL = $("#TAGS").html();
    downloadURL = "http://someurl.com/" + myURL;
});
```

and then you make your button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="download()"/>
```

having the method download do whatever you want:

```
function download() {
   if(downloadURL!="") {
      window.location.href=downloadURL;
   }
   else {
      //you don't have a value set 
   }
   downloadURL="";
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:** Create a global variable like `var downloadURL = ""` and make a function to load on page load:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var myURL = document.getElementById("TAGS").innerHTML;
    downloadURL = "http://someurl.com/" + myURL;
});
```

and then you make your button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="download()"/>
```

having the method download do whatever you want:

```
function download() {
   if(downloadURL!="") {
      window.location=downloadURL;
   }
   else {
      //you don't have a value set 
   }
   downloadURL="";
}
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed and expected thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use Jquery library with '$' sign. if you didn't install that library simply don't use it. instead, you can use pure browser JavaScript function.

```
var myURL = document.getElementById("TAGS").innerHTML;
```

myURL will be whatever inside the HTML element. 
for example: `<h3 id="TAGS">test</h3>`

myURL = test

Comment: The problem is this value is not avaiable until the page loads

Comment: you can use onload inside the html, and run the js function after the html loaded. <body onload="myFunction()"> this will run myFunction only after the html loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var myURL = $('#TAGS').val()
```

But don't forget include jQuery to you code.